# WPF Bing Map performance issues

Tags: wpf, performance, bing-maps

I've created a WPF application to show the districts of Berlin with `MapPolygon`s. Inside the `<m:Map>` tag I created 12 times a `MapItemsControl` to show the different districts. Here is the code for one:

```
<m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding dMitte}">
                <m:MapItemsControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type m:MapItemsControl}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MitteVisibility, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </m:MapItemsControl.Style>
                <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- ReSharper disable once Xaml.BindingWithContextNotResolved -->
                        <m:MapPolygon Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Opacity="0.2" Locations="{Binding Path=Locations}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl>
```

Every `ItemsSource` has a property with a `LocationCollection` where lots of `Location`s are stored to draw the correct polygons.

Everything works fine. The only problem is, that dragging the map is pretty slow and laggy. The only thing I could think of to test the performance was the built in Performance Analysis tool from Visual Studio. That gave me this result:

```
Function Name   Inclusive Samples   Exclusive Samples   Inclusive Samples % Exclusive Samples % Module Name
Microsoft.Maps.MapExtras.BitmapImageRequestQueue.DownloadThreadStart()  1   0   100,00  0,00    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.dll
--Microsoft.Maps.MapExtras.BitmapImageRequestQueue.DownloadThreadStart()    1   0   100,00  0,00    Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.dll
```

I don't really know how to solve this. Could someone lead me to the right direction?

Comment: Just to clarify that, a single district has multiple polygons? How many points are there typically in such a Locations collection?

Comment: More or less. Each district is a List<DistrictPartModel>, each with a LocationCollection. The amount depends on the size, but I got Locations from 120 up to 790.

Comment: Ok, several hundred Locations in quite a few district parts in 12 districts. That easily sums up to a few thousands polyline points, which might just be too much. Try to reduce the number of polyline points, possibly depending on the current zoom level. At higher zoom levels, show only those polylines that lie within the current viewport, at lower zoom levels reduce the number of points per polyline, e.g. by the Douglas-Ramer-Peucker algorithm.

Comment: Okay, thanks Clemens. Will try to see what I can do with that algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using vertex reduction based on zoom level. I wrote a blog post ages ago on doing this with the Bing Maps Silverlight control: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2011/12/03/vertex-reductionone-of-my-secret-weapons/ It should be fairly easy to use with the WPF control. Add a view change end event to the map and check to see if the zoom level has chanced. If it has, then update the locations of you polygons.

Alternatively, if you want to be able to render a lot more data, take a look at using the Bing Maps V8 web control in your app via a web browser control. This control has a ton of optimizations in it which allows it to render tens of thousands of polygons.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look!